# Glmer warning message to use lmer

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to fit this model below:

```
cmod_lme4C_L <- glmer(yield ~ Location + treatment + (1|block),data=df,
                      family=gaussian(link = "identity"))
```

After running this code, I get warning message:

```
Warning message:
In glmer(yield ~ Location + treatment +  :
  calling glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link) as a shortcut to lmer() is deprecated; please call lmer() directly
```

Can someone please help me understand this message?

Looks like it suggests to use `lmer`, but I am not sure how `lmer` is similar to `glmer` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is very exact in it's messaging.

When fitting a mixed-effect model with `gaussian(link = "identity")` it is equivalent to fitting a linear mixed effect model with normal random effects.

`glmer` simply changes the call to `lmer(yield ~ Location + treatment + (1|block),data=df)` and gives a warning.

The warning has been there for a very long time, and I would bet that it wont be deprecated in any near future, but for all intends and purposes you should use `lmer(...)` instead of `glmer(..., family = gaussian(link = 'identity'))`